# FLutter dart error expected value of Type 'List<Object>' but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class C like :

```
class C {
  int? first;
  int? second;
  C({
    this.first,
    this.second,
  });
}
```

and I have two classes that one of them extend from the other:

```
class A {
  int? id;
  List<C>? list;
  A({
    this.id,
    this.list,
  });
}

class B extends A{
  String? title;
  B({
    this.title,
    list,
  ):super(
    list: list,
  );
}
```

in my cubit I made instance of B class like below and I got this error :

```
B b = B(title: '', list: []);

expected value of Type List<C> but got one of type List<dynamic>
```

where is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `B` class you need to define the type for `list` when you extends `A`:

```
class B extends A {
  String? title;
  B({
    this.title,
    List<C>? list,// change to this
  }) : super(
          list: list,
        );
}
```